# Windows 8 ListView count is always 0 | winControl.selection.count(); returns 0

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I am trying to create a new windows 8 app and I am trying to implement list views.

My current problem is that document.querySelector('#myListView').winControl.selection.count(); ALWAYS returns 0.. when I select, de-select the listview ,etc..I manually loaded my items in the listView, does that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add the selectionMode to 'multi' in the data-win-option of the ListView

```
<div id="UserListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" style="border-top: 5px solid #000; min-width:500px;" 
           data-win-options="{
                               selectionMode:'multi',
                               itemTemplate:select('#itemsList'),
                               layout:{    
                               type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout}}"
         > 

    </div>
```

Then in the js file we can get the count of the  selected listview item as bellow

```
 var testCount = UserListView.winControl.selection.count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code, please? Because in my example this function wort correctly. This code in dataExample.js file:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var dataArray = [
{ title: "Basic banana", text: "Low-fat frozen yogurt", picture: "images/60banana.png" },
{ title: "Banana blast", text: "Ice cream", picture: "images/60banana.png" },
{ title: "Marvelous mint", text: "Gelato", picture: "images/60mint.png" },
{ title: "Succulent strawberry", text: "Sorbet", picture: "images/60strawberry.png" }
];

var dataList = new WinJS.Binding.List(dataArray);

var publicMembers =
    {
        itemList: dataList
    };
WinJS.Namespace.define("DataExample", publicMembers);
})();
```

In default.js I create function, which display count of selected items

```
function someFunc(mouseEvent) {

var count = document.getElementById("basicListView").winControl.selection.count();
var dlg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(count);
dlg.showAsync().operatio;
```

}

My default.html contains next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>App1</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-white.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- App1 references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dataExample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn" class="ui-button" onclick="someFunc(event)">click me</button>
<p id="button1Output"></p>

<div id="basicListView" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{     itemDataSource : DataExample.itemList.dataSource }">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465496.aspx)